# Extracting the dominant colour in an image

Tags: r, colors, extract, palette

I couldn't find a way to do this in R so thought I'd ask.

I'm trying to extract the dominant colour from a set of images (in this case, soccer jerseys) and having no luck.

The method yielding most success at the moment is to use rPlotter, e.g.

```
library(RImagePalette)
library(png)
download.file("http://i.imgur.com/UqW6ZLo.png", "kit.png", mode = "wb")
test <- readPNG("kit.png")
pal <- image_palette(test, 10, median, TRUE)
display_palette(pal)
```

but there seems to be no pattern to which colour is the dominant one by eye and where it appears (finding only 1 colour for the palette gives a merging of them).

I had also tried

```
download.file("http://i.imgur.com/UqW6ZLo.png", "kit.png", mode = "wb")
test <- readPNG("kit.png")
list <- c()
for (x in 1:30){
pal <- image_palette(test, 10, median, TRUE)
list <- append(list, pal[1])
}
display_palette(list)
```

and I think if there's a way to find the median HEX colour from `list` that should also do the trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: R colors are #rrggbbaa. You need to tabulate and find the most frequent values. Start by reading ?colors. Then follow all the links.

Comment: ach- sorry, updated with correct packages now. I have the same problem with extract_colours. There's clearly more "red-ish" colours on the image but I can't figure out how to get a red cluster to fall out as the first element

Comment: First, define dominant color. If it is the most frequent RGB combination, it's not really a R package issue but simple math issue. Convert RGB values into a single value, for example, one of 256^3 values and then make histogram to find the most frequent one. But I have to warn that color is very deceptive as different RGB combinations can be seen as identical.

Comment: yeah,I mean I'm not contesting that at all. My point is that the k-means clsutering method of generating a palette does work. More times than not it finds what I would consider "the dominant colour" (or close enough). Its a problem of then extracting that from the list of first colour found in the second chunk I posted

Comment: `rPlotter`'s `extract_colours` uses kmeans, and it sorts the output based on rgb content (check the code to see this), not on which color in the output is most dominant.  When you use `RImagePalette`, you're not using kmeans.  You're using the median cut algorithm.  Now, for your second code chunk, have you tried anything to extract the modal (or median or mean) value?  Does it not work well?